# MongoVUE user creation seems not to work properly

Tags: mongodb, mongovue

I've installed mongodb server v.2.6.1 and followed all the installation steps (as in previous times) and worked fine (I run the server and from another cmd I connect to it and everything is ok).

I also installed MongoVUE v.1.6.9 and when I create users from there, they don't appear when in the cmd I write `show users`, they only appear when I write `db.system.users.find()`.

So if I want to be able to connect to any database, even from MonogoVUE, I need to create the users from de cmd as `db.addUser("username", "password")` (I know it is deprecated for my current version but it works) and then I get different users when I write `show users` or `db.system.users.find()` since the former are the ones created in the cmd and the latter the ones created in MongoVUE.

This behaviour seems strange to me and I can't figure out why. Maybe I am missing some config parameters but in others installations I never had such problems.

I've reinstalled MongoVUE but I'm not sure if I'm getting rid of the previous bad config since after reinstalling it knows the parameters of my connection (port, user...). My OS is Windows7 with SP1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some research I finally decided to install the previous stable version of the mongodb server (v 2.4.10) and that's how I fixed it.

Version 2.6.x seemed to show that hiccup with MongoVUE in my environment (Windows7 with SP1).
I still don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB 2.6 introduced a new model for storing authentication data, as well as additional security features like user-defined roles. In MongoDB 2.6 all user and role information is now stored in the [`system.users`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-users-collection/) and [`system.roles`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-roles-collection/) collections in the `admin` database. There are also new shell helpers and commands for [User and Role Management](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-user-role-management/).

Some commands like `db.addUser()` have been deprecated in the `mongo` 2.6 shell and mapped to their modern equivalents so they will continue to work until you learn the new commands.

For example:

```
 > db.addUser("username", "password")
 WARNING: The 'addUser' shell helper is DEPRECATED. Please use 'createUser' instead
 Successfully added user: { "user" : "username", "roles" : [ "dbOwner" ] }
```

If you created users in a previous version of MongoDB you may see the old database-specific `system.users` collections which are left after migration to the 2.6+ authentication format. These are no longer used.

Comment: I am sorry @Stennie but although all what this answer says is true, still don't help me at all.
I mean this is a new installation (I installed it before in other computers) and what is confusing to me is that are merely the users created with `db.addUser` (deprecated) the ones that are able to connect to the databases and not the ones created with MongoVUE (which I assume must be using the new commands for Use and Role Management).

Comment: @gugol: `show users` in MongoDB 2.6 will show you the correct user information. Using `db.system.users.find()` in a database other than `admin` will show old information from your 2.4 configuration that have been migrated. As mentioned, in MongoDB 2.6 the `system.users` data now lives in the `admin` database. NOTE: MongoVUE 1.6.9 pre-dates MongoDB 2.6; it *should* continue to work adding users via the legacy interface but I haven't tested this in MongoVUE yet.